# Exiting sql.Rows.Next() for loop

Tags: sqlite, go

I am iterating through sqliteDB rows in a for loop using rows.Next(). However based on a bool value from a channel I need to stop iterating through rows and exit.

```
for rows.Next() {
    select {
    case <-exitChannel:
        fmt.Println("\n Exiting")
        break
    default:
                fmt.Println("\nEntering")
        doSomething()

    }
}
```

Even though the exitChannel is true, the code never enters the respective case and "Exiting" is never printed

To test if its a go problem or a sqliteDB issue, I ran a continuous for loop without rows.Next() to check if the code enters the exit case. It does!

```
for {
    select {
    case <-exitChannel:
        fmt.Println("\n Exiting")
        break
    default:
                fmt.Println("\nEntering")
    }
}
```

This code does print "Exiting"

Comment: "`Exiting` is never printed" - what is printed (i.e. are you seeing `Entering`  output continually?) - just want to confirm that `doSomething()` is not blocking. Can you please also confirm what "exitChannel is true" means (are you closing the channel, or `exitChannel <- true`). Unfortunately I think this is going to be difficult to answer without a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: Thanks for your response but labelling the for loop and breaking worked

Comment: In that case there was an issue with the question (`Exiting` will have been printed but, I guess, scrolled up too fast for you to notice).

Answer (score -2):

Sharing the solution of the problem:

```
for rows.Next() {
    forLoop:
    select {
    case <-exitChannel:
        fmt.Println("\n Exiting")
        break forLoop
    default:
        fmt.Println("\nEntering")
        doSomething()

    }
}
```

Comment: That should not work if your original code failed; this new code effectively does the same thing (it loops through all results [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/8sk_gYR1uPu)). The label needs to be outside the loop ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/BRF4mgaeND3)) - as per the comment from @mkopriva on the deleted answer.